# How to convert list of bytes (unicode) to Python string?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a list of bytes (8 bit bytes, or in C/C++ language they form wchar_t type string), they form an UNICODE string (byte by byte), how to convert those values into a Python string, tried a few things, but none could join those 2 bytes into 1 character and build an entire string from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Converting a sequence of bytes to a Unicode string is done by calling the `decode()` method on that `str` (in Python 2.x) or `bytes` (Python 3.x) object.

If you actually have a list of bytes, then, to get this object, you can use  `''.join(bytelist)` or `b''.join(bytelist)`.

You need to specify the encoding that was used to encode the original Unicode string.

However, the term "Python string" is a bit ambiguous and also version-dependent. The Python `str` type stands for a byte string in Python 2.x and a Unicode string in Python 3.x. So, in Python 2, just doing `''.join(bytelist)` will give you a `str` object.

Demo for Python 2:

```
In [1]: 'тест'
Out[1]: '\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82'

In [2]: bytelist = ['\xd1', '\x82', '\xd0', '\xb5', '\xd1', '\x81', '\xd1', '\x82']

In [3]: ''.join(bytelist).decode('utf-8')
Out[3]: u'\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442'

In [4]: print ''.join(bytelist).decode('utf-8') # encodes to the terminal encoding
тест

In [5]: ''.join(bytelist) == 'тест'
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: brilliant answer, you have saved me a lot of time, since this is my first try at Python :), thanks a lot Lev

Comment: Demo for Python 3?

Comment: @stackprotector in Python 3, `Out[3]` from the answer would show a regular (Unicode) string. Output 4 would print the string (almost the same thing).

Answer (score 15):

you can also convert the byte list into string list using the `decode()`

```
stringlist=[x.decode('utf-8') for x in bytelist]
```

Comment: This would only work for ASCII bytes. Anything else *will* fail because you can’t decode any value over `b'\x7f'` as UTF-8, which is what the code in this answer would do. And given that the OP has stated they have 8-bit bytes from a C++ `wchar_t` data type it is almost *guaranteed* to not be ASCII *or* UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked the best for me:

```
import codecs

print(type(byteData)) # <class 'bytes'>
strData = codecs.decode(byteData, 'UTF-8')
```